# How to convert external graphics automatically to black&white

Tags: color

For the last ten week me and 9 other students have worked on a report. And the final version of the report needs to be printed in black&white (so no color). The easiest method is use the grey setting of the printer. However, many picture in the report are now unclear. Therefore, I would like to ask you guys the following question: "Is there an option in latex which automatically prints the pdf in black&white?"

This is the following setup I use for latex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{a4paper}
    \geometry{width=0.7\paperwidth,height=0.8\paperheight}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}             
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{titlesec}                       
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eurosym}                            
\usepackage{gensymb}                            
\usepackage{appendix}                       
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{booktabs}                       
\bibliographystyle{unsrt} 

\usepackage[monochrome]{color} % if I use this I get an error: option clash for package color.
%%%%%%%%%%%
```

and if I put in behind the documentclass like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,monochrome]{scrbook} % it still prints the pdf in color.
```

I hope one of you guys can help with this.

Comment: do you run `latex` or `pdflatex`?

Comment: The answer provide below does work, however the figures in the latex document are still in color. My main concern is to get the pictures to be printed in b&w.

@Herbert: I use texnicenter with the option latex => pdf. Does this answers your question.

Thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: I searched a little but didn’t find an answer how to convert included graphics to greyscale. The `monochrome` option simply converts commands like `\color{green}` to b&w. But it doesn’t (and shouldn’t) affect on external graphics. I think you have to convert the graphics yourself … May you would like to change the title to something like “How to convert external graphics automatically to black&white“

Answer (score 5):

I guess that one of the other packages loads `color` with options, but I don’t know which …

Note that it’s recommended to use the newer `xcolor` instead of `pdfcolor`

### Update

`pdfpages` causes the error.

### Update 2

Load `(x)color` before `pdfpages`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[monochrome]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
Test \color{green} Green
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for the same solution. Until now, I just found the unsatisfying answer that all included pictures or in your case pdf-pages are not affected by the `monocrome` option. See https://superuser.com/questions/165461/setting-color-latex-generated-pdf-to-print-in-black-white

Maybe to solve this issue you want to convert your pdf file `pdffile.pdf` at first to grayscale. The following application of your pdf-converter (as a shell command) should work in principle - but it unfortunately does not to me:

```
$ lpr -P PDF -o saturation=0 pdffile.pdf
```

Maybe someone can improve my answer.